# Using accessors with pivot table fields in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I've currently got a few models that have many to many relationships via laravel. here's the structure:

```
users
    id
    username
    ...

games
    id
    title
    ...

game_user
    game_id
    user_id
    system
```

Now, my models look a little like this:

```
<?php

class Game extends Eloquent
{
    /**
     * A game is owned by many users
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User')->withPivot('system');
    }


<?php

class User extends Eloquent
{
    /**
     * A user has many games.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function games()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Game')->withPivot('system');
    }
```

Now, this all works fine. However, I wish to use a mutator upon the system field from the pivot table. I can't find any documentation on this and the following (in both the User and Game models) does not work:

```
public function getSystemAttribute($val)
{
    return $val.' Testing';
}
```

Comment: can you dump the table's data

Comment: I can do so, but it's very basic.

Answer (score 9):

I haven't tested but this should work.

```
public function getSystemAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->pivot->system . ' Testing';
}

...

foreach ($user->games as $game)
{
    echo $game->system;
}
```

The value getting passed in is being pulled from the models attributes. There is no system attribute so you should get NULL. We can just ignore that and pull the value from the pivot table directly.

Comment: You don't need the $value argument in there.

Comment: In order to access the *system* attribute (in views/controllers) you need to add the attribute name to the `appends` property on the model first

Answer (score 4):

You need to define an accessor for the pivot's `system` property and **add the attribute name to the appends property on the model**. The whole procedure follows

1) Define an accessor in the parent Model from where we want to access the attribute:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Game extends Model
{
    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public function getSystemAttribute() // the name can be anything e.g getFooAttribute
    {
        return $this->pivot->system;
    }
}
```

2)  ***(to avoid getting NULL!)*** Add the attribute name to the appends property on the model (see  [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json)).

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Book extends Model
{
    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = ['system']; 
}
```

3)  Now you can access that new created `system` attribute from the parent Model:

```
$user = App\User::find($id);
foreach ($user->games as $game)
{
    echo $game->system;
}
```

Of course, like with every accessor,  you might also "alter" the value of the pivot table before accessing it, for instance:

```
public function getSystemAttribute()
{
    return $this->pivot->foo .'Hello word!'; //append the ""Hello word!" string to the end of the `foo` attribute value
}
```

Finally notice that *the name of the accessor can be anything* like `getFooAttribute`, `getBarAttribute`, `getBarBazAttribute`. In that case the append would be protected `$appends = ['foo'];` and you could again access the pivot's `foo` property via the parent Model like `$game->foo`

Comment: There a problem for this. When you call a Book model (not relationship), `pivot` is not define -> `getSystemAttribute` error. 
Try check `pivot` before, we alway get `system` = null for Book::find(1).

How to only append in relationship method?

Answer (score 2):

I found this question interesting, so I started playing around with the code.

If you need to access a **specific entry**, here's my solution:

```
public function getSystemAttribute($game){
    foreach($this->games as $value){
        if($value->id==$game->id){
            $value->pivot->system = 'foo';
            $value->pivot->save();
        }
    }
}
```

which you can simply call with:

```
$user->getSystemAttribute($game)
```

Regarding the accessor, I couldn't find any other way without itarating the collection. There are prettier ways of iterating the collection, but this was not the scope of this question. From the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables), you can see how any attribute of the pivot table can be accessed.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank You! I was looking around like crazy on a way to add the data to the pivot table, not access it, and couldn't find anything anywhere. Everything is only about attaching pivot, not caring about the data columns...

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to be able to insert your mutated `system` attribute on your Response's (JSON, etc.), then you should add the following to both Models (game + user).

```php
protected $appends = array('system');
```

Comment: Just for the record, this is valid if you are using Laravel >= 4.0.8. Furthermore, you'd still need the 'system' attribute accessor for this directive to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

My main problem Is that I have some json encoded objects stored as text in my pivot table. I would like to automatically encode and decode them.

So what I came up with, because of the lack of a real alternative, is a basic workaround for the accessor (json decode) functionality. I've first tried to use the [approach provided by Collin James](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19987043/983992) but didn't like the fact that it creates a new custom attribute instead of manipulating `pivot->random_attribute`.

In my tables I allways have an `id` attribute, so I wrote an accessor for the id attribute and included the pivot data manipulation.

```php
public function getIdAttribute($id) {

    //Decode random_attribute
    if(isset($this->pivot->random_attribute)) {
        $this->pivot->random_attribute = json_decode($this->pivot->random_attribute);
    }

    return $id;
}
```

Unfortunately I couldn't manage the mutator in a similar way. But for me the accessor is a lot more important.